# Google Docs page overview vs. MS Word page overview

Tags: google-docs

I'm looking for a solution/workaround for:

Google Docs does not provide a comprehensive page view as does MS Word. For example, when a Google doc is more than one page, there appears to be no method to see all pages simultaneously *side by side* as can be done in Word. Google Docs allows only a page after page- scrolling down or up only. Because of this, an efficient, multiple pages view *of all pages* on one screen cannot be accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there is no workaround for this. Google Docs does not support such view mode/overview. The only thing you can do is to zoom out to see the whole page(s) but not all of them at once like in MS Word.

[image: 0]